# Issue with aix sed command

Tags: sed, aix

I am trying to uncomment "/usr/lib/sa/sa1" or "/usr/lib/sa/sa2" entries from one of the configuration file.

Below is the regex:

```
"^[0-9].*/usr/lib/sa/sa(1|2)"
```

Eg:

```
#0 * * * * /usr/lib/sa/sa1 1200 3 &
#5 23 * * * /usr/lib/sa/sa2 -s 0:00 -e 23:01 -i 3600 -ubcwyaqvm &
```

Output should be:

```
0 * * * * /usr/lib/sa/sa1 1200 3 &
5 23 * * * /usr/lib/sa/sa2 -s 0:00 -e 23:01 -i 3600 -ubcwyaqvm &
```

Tried the below "sed" command but no luck:

```
sed -e '/^#.*\/usr\/lib\/sa\/sa\(1\|2\)/s/^#//g' adm
```

Can you please let me know where am I going wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you replace `(1|2)` with `[12]`, any change? (I suspect that this is a BRE-vs-ERE problem; an older UNIX's sed is likely to only support the very baseline POSIX Basic Regular Expressions syntax).

Comment: ...alternately, if you check the man page for that copy of sed, does it support a `-r` or `-E` to turn on POSIX ERE syntax?

Comment: ...if it _is_ BRE, then you can also use `\(1|2\)` -- without the backslashes, the parens match only themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sed '/^#.*\/usr\/lib\/sa\/sa[12]/s/^#//'
```

Here, no grouping construct is used, no alternation operator is used either. It is possible as the `1` and `2` are single char alternatives, and bracket expressions are supported in all versions of `sed`.

Also, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/9M5n94).